# How to avoid "Bad Escape Character" passing variable to SSH?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ssh, environment-variables

I have a string variable passed in from the command line that I want to use in SSH.

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts ":b:e:" arg; do
  case "${arg}" in
    b) b="$OPTARG";;
    e) e="$OPTARG";;
  esac
done

echo "locally using $b and $e"

ssh @myhost "$b $e" << 'EOF'

echo "Remotely using $b and $e"

EOF
```

OUTPUT:

```
locally using 06-30-20-18-10 and 06-30-20-23-59
Bad escape character '06-30-20-23-59'
```

Running with: bash file.sh -b 06-30-20-18-10 -e 06-30-20-23-59

How do I avoid the bad escape character & use the variable remotely?

Comment: Can you show us exactly how you are running the script? It looks like it will attempt to *execute* the expansion of `"$b"` (in place of the user's login shell) and pass the expansion of `echo "Remotely using $b"` to its standard input. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @steeldriver I am running the script like this: bash file.sh -b "06-30-20-23-59" -e "06-30-20-23-59". I want to be able to parse the string/date in SSH

Comment: Well I can't reproduce that - the error message `Bad escape character` suggests that `-e "06-30-20-23-59"` is being passed to the `ssh` command itself (see `man ssh`), which is not what your script appears to do.

Comment: I think the problem may have been related to my ssh call also having: $*

Comment: I updated the call to: ssh @myhost "bash -s $b $e $customer" << 'EOF', it now doesn't give the "Bad escape character" message, but the variables are empty

Comment: The `<< 'EOF'` here doc is interpreted on the localhost, by the parent shell, and sent to the `STDIN` (file descriptor 0) of the `ssh` command, on the localhost, and is discarded. Either build your command as a 1-liner (`ssh @myhost "env b=\"$b\" e=\"$e\" $b $e `), although why you have `$b` as the command to execute looks like a mistake.  **OR** use an `expect` script, if your task is complex. Read `man expect`.

Comment: @waltinator I don't want to execute $b as a command; I am just new to bash scripting. My goal is to use $b as a string variable.