# How to use command line variable in an SSH command?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ssh

EDIT: I want to loop through all files containing variable c in their name, but for some reason this script loops through all files in the directory.... shouldn't the "*$c*" only match on file names containing c?

I also want to parse out the numbers between dashes for $b and $e

I think this is still a problem with improperly accessing the three variables

```
while getopts ":a:b:c:" arg; do
  case "${arg}" in
    a) a="$OPTARG";;
    b) b="$OPTARG";;
    c) c="$OPTARG";;
  esac
done

echo "Locally using begin: $a , end: $b, and customer: $c"

cd "/opt/data"

a="$(echo "$a" | sed -e 's/[-]/\\&/g')"
b="$(echo "$b" | sed -e 's/[-]/\\&/g')"

ssh -o ... -i $Host <<EOF


echo "Remotely using begin: $a , end: $b, and customer: $c"

find . -type f -name "*$c*" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; 
do
  echo $file
done
```

Comment: If you want `$c` to be expanded by the local shell (i.e. before the contents of the heredoc are passed to the remote shell) then you need to remove the quotes around `'EOF'`. However I'm uncertain what you're really asking since I don't understand what you're expecting `$*` to do here (what parameters you are calling the script with?)

Comment: @steeldriver i'm calling the script like this: bash script.sh -b 06-30-20-18-10 -e 06-30-20-23-59 -c name

Comment: ... so when you ran the (since removed) `ssh -o ... -i $Host $*` that would have passed `-b 06-30-20-18-10 -e 06-30-20-23-59 -c name` to the `ssh` program itself - which would have errored out (because `-e` is used to set the ssh escape character, and `06-30-20-23-59` is not a character for example). Even in circumstances where `$*` is valid, most times what you should be using is `"$@"` though.

Comment: This seems to be a re-hash of your previous question [How to avoid "Bad Escape Character" passing variable to SSH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398606/how-to-avoid-bad-escape-character-passing-variable-to-ssh) - I think at this point it would be better to ask about the actual problem you are trying to solve (which seems to be about taking user-supplied patterns and searching for matching filenames on a remote host?)

Comment: @steeldriver the actual problem is checking the dates on the file names (that contain the $c name) and checking if they are within the interval of $b and $e

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your script.

The first is that *getopts stops processing when it encounters the first non-option argument*. Since you haven't declared `-e` as an option argument, it gets left unprocessed and no value is assigned to `c`. Consider:

```
$ cat myscript
#!/bin/bash

printf  'Processing option arguments:\n'
while getopts ":a:b:c:" arg; do
  case "${arg}" in
    a) a="$OPTARG"; echo "\$a is $a";;
    b) b="$OPTARG"; echo "\$b is $b";;
    c) c="$OPTARG"; echo "\$c is $c";;
  esac
done
printf 'Done.\n\n'

shift $((OPTIND - 1))

printf 'Remaining (non-option) arguments:\n'
printf '%s\n' "$@"
```

run as suggested in [your comment above](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399768/how-to-use-command-line-variable-in-an-ssh-command?noredirect=1#comment2427180_1399768):

```
$ ./myscript -b 06-30-20-18-10 -e 06-30-20-23-59 -c name otherarg whatever
Processing option arguments:
$b is 06-30-20-18-10
Done.

Remaining (non-option) arguments:
06-30-20-23-59
-c
name
otherarg
whatever
```

Second, *even if a value is assigned to variable c in the local shell, quoting the heredoc's end marker* `'EOF'` *prevents the local shell from expanding it*. So the remote shell receives `$c`, and expands it to its (almost certainly empty) value there.

Correcting both issues:

```
$ cat myscript
#!/bin/bash

printf  'Processing option arguments:\n'
while getopts ":a:b:c:e:" arg; do
  case "${arg}" in
    a) a="$OPTARG"; echo "\$a is $a";;
    b) b="$OPTARG"; echo "\$b is $b";;
    c) c="$OPTARG"; echo "\$c is $c";;
    e) e="$OPTARG"; echo "\$e is $e";;
  esac
done
printf 'Done.\n\n'

shift $((OPTIND - 1))

printf 'Remaining (non-option) arguments:\n'
printf '%s\n' "$@"

ssh localhost << EOF

printf '%s\n' "$a" "$b" "$c" "$e"

EOF
```

then

```
$ ./myscript -b 06-30-20-18-10 -e 06-30-20-23-59 -c name
Processing option arguments:
$b is 06-30-20-18-10
$e is 06-30-20-23-59
$c is name
Done.

Remaining (non-option) arguments:

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Enter passphrase for key '/home/steeldriver/.ssh/id_rsa':
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-143-generic x86_64)

You have mail.


06-30-20-18-10
name
06-30-20-23-59
```

Comment: thank you for clarifying that. There is a part of this I am still stuck on though.

Comment: I want to iterate over the files & print the ones containing the "$c" parameter. I know there are files matching "$c", but with the code below it is not finding any matches. Do I have to modify the "$c" variable somehow?


find . -type f -name "*$c*" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; 
do
  printf "$file"
done